# Access Django's Static files on Amazon S3 with 'same-origin' referrer policy

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

Since Django 3.0, SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY was added and also included on the `python manage.py check --deploy` command. In order to make to make my Django project read media files from Amazon S3, I previously had mine set to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`, as well as a S3 policy allowing for the programmatic user to do everything and another policy that checked if the referrer header was set to my domain (similar to what's been described in this question [Amazon S3 Bucket Policy Referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502448/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-referer)).

But that was a very rudimentary hotlink protection and I was advised at the Django Forums to switch to `same-origin`.

However, now my site can no longer get any of its asset files (403 Error) and navigating through `django-storages` and S3 docs searching for an answer has proved to be tough and fruitless so far. :(

**Here's what I currently have:**

On the Django side, I have `django-storages` configured with:

- `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'authenticated-read'`
- `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = 'same-origin'`
- `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'`

On AWS, I have the following policy (the access policy by referrer has been removed):

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow programatic admin to handle bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:user/bucket-manager"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And the programatic user has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I had the sense that what I lacked was to add the `bucket-manager` user to the bucket's ACL, but the UI asks for there canonical ID and I, for the live of me, cannot find it.