# Protect s3 Object from Public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to protect my s3 object from Public access and the object can only be accessed from my origin. How can I do that? I tried by setting Objects **Access control** to Private, then Set in the buckets CORS settings, Allowed origin to my origin with the method GET but I'm getting an error while accessing the object.

How do I set the bucket to access the bucket objects only from my origin?

Comment: what error are you getting?  how are you trying to access these objects?  what are your CORS settings specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by "object can only be accessed from my origin"? Are you referring to Amazon CloudFront? Please edit your question to include FULL details of your configuration and what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: @JDD Ther error was access denied.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I was looking for some methods to secure s3. like I'm having a domain say example.com and the object an only accessed from example.com . I guess cloudfront OAI is what I was looking for.

Comment: If your desire is "this object is accessible only if somebody is using my website" sounds like the use [`referer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502448/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-referer), but that is easily bypassed. If your goal is to only serve content to authenticated users, the look at using [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). If you want any further advice, please Edit your Question to provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you *might* be asking how to make an Amazon S3 bucket accessible to a specific Amazon CloudFront distribution.

From [Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html):

> To restrict access to content that you serve from Amazon S3 buckets, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Create a special CloudFront user called an origin access identity (OAI) and associate it with your distribution.
> 2. Configure your S3 bucket permissions so that CloudFront can use the OAI to access the files in your bucket and serve them to your users. Make sure that users can’t use a direct URL to the S3 bucket to access a file there.
>
> After you take these steps, users can only access your files through CloudFront, not directly from the S3 bucket.